# Decimal to Binary convertion in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal, converters

I try to write this code without using any arrays or other stuff but only using loops, I wrote it down it works fine but there is a problem about it and I couldn't find any solution to that: The problem is it doesn't write the zeros 
for exmp:
if I type 43 it converts it correctly : 101011
but when I type 12 it shows only 11 instead of 1100

```
int decimal,binr=0;
int bin=0,rem,i;
printf("enter the decimal number:");
scanf("%d",&decimal);
for(i=1;decimal!=0;i++){

    rem=decimal%2;
    binr= binr*10 +rem;
    decimal=decimal/2;  


}
for(i=0;binr!=0;i++){

    rem = binr%10;
    bin= bin*10 +rem ;
    binr=binr/10;

}
printf("the binary equivalent is: %d",bin);
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger to trace your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is misbehaving because you exit when your accumulator is 0. If instead, you count the bits, those zeros won't be ignored. And note that once you have read the input into a variable, it is no longer represented decimally, so you can go straight to binary, counting the bits as the number is reversed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    unsigned decimal = 12;
    unsigned reverse = 0;
    unsigned bits = 0;
    while(decimal != 0) {
        reverse = reverse * 2 + decimal % 2;
        decimal /= 2;
        bits++;
    }
    if(bits == 0) {                          // special case
        printf("0");
    }
    while(bits != 0) {
        printf("%u", reverse % 2);
        reverse /= 2;
        bits--;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
1100
```

Comment: Could use `do { reverse = reverse * 2 + decimal % 2; decimal /= 2; bits++; } while (decimal);` and then drop the special case.

Comment: @chux I missed that, actually only noticed the exception as an afterthought ;(

Comment: @Weather Vane just a single problem is there way to store data instead of typing it one by one because I need that data I will use it somewhere else but I cant do it because it is printing it one by one ?

Comment: @HasanBilalAdak yes, you can write `'0'` + *each_bit_value* into successive index positions in a `char[]` array, and then terminate it with `nul` to make it a C string.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to debug your code you would see it very clear.
If you run 12 in your b10 to b2 program, it would do this:

```
result=0, value=12
  ret = 12 % 2 -> 0
  -> result = result * 10 + ret -> 0*10 + 0
result=0, value=6
  ret = 6 % 2 -> 0
  -> result = result * 10 + ret -> 0*10 + 0
result=0, value=3
...
```

You can see your program is not doing what it is supposed to.

Also, don't use for loops here. It is clearly a while loop (you never even used the i variable, why is the increase for?).

If you do some research, you will see a lot of implementations of the decimal/binary algorithm implementation.

Comment: the i variable is just for keeping the loop continue until the decimal is equals 0, I did do lot of research and I know few ways to do this conversion but what I need is this kind of code just using the loops. my only problem is as I said before The program is not showing the zeros